# How to insert and fetch raw json values in mysql using node js

Tags: mysql, json, node.js

I have a column in mysql table `jsonvalues` type blob I'm storing below raw json values into this field

```
{"name":"john","mob":"23434"}
```

but when I'm fetching from the db in node js, json values are changing to

```
{"type":"Buffer","data":[34,123,
```

I want to display the values as raw json in html column, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's zero JavaScript code here so this isn't really a complete question. What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily store JSON into mysql table - just serialize JSON to string (`const jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);`).

Thus suitable mysql field types are VARCHAR, TEXT or bigger text types.

De-serialize stored string to get Json object back (`const jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);`). Then you can use your raw json whatever you want. Hope that helps..

Comment: The best suitable mysql field type is the `JSON` type.

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer myself, i have changed the `mysql field type from blob to varchar` and it is displaying on the result in node js and the same in html also.